# How to create this type of abstract model shape

Tags: modeling

How to create this type of abstract model shape. Looking to create the model (red mark below reference image). I tried with tissue addon but not get the result. Any other way or how to achieve it. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is to create a b&w picture from your photo:

[image]

Convert to vector in Inkscape (it may be doable through Blender), import the SVG, right click and convert to mesh:

[image]

Press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]